# Split array based on value for a single dimentional array with key and value

Tags: php

I am trying to split an array to different arrays based on values.
This is my array

```
$myArray=('x'=>'europe','y'=>'europe','a'=>'USA','b'=>'USA','c'=>'Canada');
```

I want to split the array based on value like below

```
$newList[europe]=(x,y);
$newList[USA]=(a,b);
$newLsit[Canada]=(c);
```

I tried the following

```
foreach($myArray as $key =>$value){
$myList[$value]=$key;
}
```

and

```
foreach($myArray as $key => $value){
echo $key;
if($value=='USA')$myList['USA']=$key;
if($value=='europe')$myList['europe']=$key;
if($value=='Canada')$myList['Canada']=$key;
}
```

the output is the same

```
 Array ( [europe] => y [USA] => b [Canada] => c )
```

I do not understand what the issue could be. Any help is much appriciated.

Comment: What is expected resulting array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have more countries, then if loop is not a good method. Instead of that you can create array for each country using foreach statement. Please see the below code, it may help you.

```
    $myArray = array('x'=>'europe','y'=>'europe','a'=>'USA','b'=>'USA','c'=>'Canada');
    $new_array = array();
    foreach($myArray as $key=>$val)
    {
      $new_array[$val][] = $key;
    }
    print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple way.

```
$myArray= array('x'=>'europe','y'=>'europe','a'=>'USA','b'=>'USA','c'=>'Canada');
$grouped = array();
foreach ($myArray as $key => $group) {
    $grouped[$group][] = $key;
}
print_r($grouped);
```

DEMO http://phpio.net/s/9lw

Answer (score 2):

you need to use this

```
$myList = array();
foreach($myArray as $key => $value)
{
 if($value=='USA') $myList['USA'][]=$key;
 if($value=='europe') $myList['europe'][]=$key;
 if($value=='Canada') $myList['Canada'][]=$key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An `array` can not have same `key` multiple times. So in look the `key` is being overwritten by the latest value. You need to save the array in nested way.

```
$myArray= array('x'=>'europe','y'=>'europe','a'=>'USA','b'=>'USA','c'=>'Canada');

foreach($myArray as $key => $value) {
  // Value as the key & key in sub array
  $new[$value][] = $key; 
}

var_dump($new);
```

**Output**

```
array(3) {
  ["europe"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "x"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "y"
  }
  ["USA"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "b"
  }
  ["Canada"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "c"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to push array when exists and assign when not present- This will godd for any warning. Use the [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) function to check the value is in the array as key or not??

```
$myArray = array('x'=>'europe','y'=>'europe','a'=>'USA','b'=>'USA','c'=>'Canada');
$newList = array();

foreach($myArray as $key => $value){
    if(array_key_exists($value, $newList))
        array_push($newList[$value], $key);
    else    
        $newList[$value][] = $key;
}
print_r($newList);
```

[Online Example](https://3v4l.org/WJ3rm)